# Remote help requested to help install AKS with static IP and LetsEncrypt

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster. I follow mainly this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip

Unfortunately, I go from error to error and from forum post to forum post after reinstalling the K8 cluster. I have the feeling the source underneath changes or the versions do not match and am keep running circles.

I had the cluster running on an azure fixed IP with DNS: like https://mydnsname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
Am I allowed to do this? It worked for a couple of weeks, but stopped. Or should I take own dns address to get rid of the problem?

Namely, Google and Edge browsers blocked the web page as the root certificate was invalid. No idea why my cluster broke that sudden. So I tried over a couple of times to reinstall the cluster from my .azli notebook. Still same error. So I changed NGINX from ingress-ngnix to nginx-ing nginx-stable/nginx-ingress, but without success either. I also come across errors like version warnings. So what belongs to what to get this successfully running?

Same version thing with cert manager. Is version v1.1.0 the latest and does it belong to the ingress-nginx or the nginx-stable/nginx-ingress ?

I miss the idea of 1 framework like .net core/ .net 5 in this new world I am entering. I feel like gluing a lot together, and keep fingers crossed if it keeps on working...my 2 cents. Is there somebody out there able to spend a couple of hours remote to get this beast done together instead of me running circles? Or pass me through what versions I should use to get it working (again)..and (forever?)?

Comment: I managed to get the cluster up and running again. Spend days on it, For others. read this one: [link](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3334) and use the production version of certmanager/ jetstack instead of staging so that real certificates are handed out. also use 'kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.1.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml

# Helm v3+
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v1.1.0 
  #--set installCRDs=true'

Answer (score 0):

Rewritting this answer from comment section.
As @[V4A001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12456599/v4a001)  write use the production version of certmanager/ jetstack instead of staging - real certificates will be handed out.
Take look:  [jetstack-certmanager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3334).

You have two   possibilities:

**1. Install CRDs with  `kubectl` command**

```sh
# For Kubernetes <1.15 execute command
$ kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.1.0/cert-manager-legacy.crds.yaml

# For Kubernetes 1.15+ execute command
$ kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.1.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

**2.** **Install CRDs using Helm release**

```sh
# For Helm v2
$ helm install \
  --name cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v1.1.0 \
  jetstack/cert-manager \
  # --set installCRDs=true
  
# For Helm v3+
$ helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v1.1.0 \
  # --set installCRDs=true
```

For automation and management the [CRDs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) as part of Helm release, you have to add the `--set installCRDs` flag set to `true` to your Helm installation command.

More info: [certmanager-kubernetes](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/).